# Apex Rest Callout GET Method with Basic Authorization

Tags: apex, httprequest

When I m calling that from POSTMAN with the access token,etc.. I m getting the response. But when I m calling this from Apex it is giving Unauthorized(status:401). I don't know why. See code below:

```
public static httpResponse callOut () {
    HTTP h = new HTTP();
    String httpMethod = 'GET';
    String accountId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    String authToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    String endpoint = 'https://api.apifonica.com/v2/accounts/' + accountId ;
    httpRequest req = new httpRequest();
    String authValue = accountId + ':' + authToken;
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(accountId +':'+authToken);
    String authorizationHeader = 'Basic' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization',authorizationHeader);
    req.setMethod(httpMethod);
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    //req.setTimeout(120000);
    //Use the HTTP Class to send the httpRequest and receive an httpResponse
    httpResponse res = h.send(req);
    System.debug('response' + res.getBody());
    return res;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of Postman:
[image]
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you tested end point in Postman right? can you please share the screen shot!!

Comment: Yes, i updated the question

Comment: I think you're missing a space in your header, try: `String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);`

Comment: Okay..@RaeL_kid please answer the question.Its good for other viewers reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space in your authorization header string, use this instead:

`String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);`